# How to concatenate two or more fields in material-table react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rows, material-table

I'm trying to create a "Name" column in my material-table with concatenated `firstname, lastname` from my array, but It only accepts one data per field.

Any suggestion or help to make it possible ?

```react
const client = {
  firstname: "Tracy",
  lastname: "Santos",
  address: {
    address1: "Manila",
    address2: "Philippines",
  }
}

const columns = [
  { title: 'Name', field: 'client.firstname' + ' ' + 'client.lastname' },
  { title: 'Address', field: 'client.address.address1' + ' ' + 'client.address.address2' },
]
```

```
<MaterialTable
  column={ columns }
  data={ client }
/>
```

Comment: The `field` attribute is looking for a specific key in the data object, it does not look for the data value itself. You should update your data to include such a new field, and fill it with the combination of the first and last names.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate approach that doesn't require modifying the data you pass to the table would be to use a custom render function for that field.

```
{
  render: (client) => {
    return `${client.firstName} ${client.lastName}`;
  },
  title: 'Client',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your columns need to have a `field` value that exists in the data object.

So, change your `columns` object to be:

```js
const columns = [
  { title: 'Name', field: 'fullName' },
  { title: 'Address', field: 'fullAddress' },
];
```

Once you have the columns, you need to modify the data you pass into the component.

```js
const client = {
  firstname: 'Tracy',
  lastname: 'Santos',
  address: {
    address1: 'Manila',
    address2: 'Philippines',
  }
}

// Create the new object
const newData = {
  fullName: `${client.firstname} ${client.lastname}`,
  fullAddress: `${client.address.address1}, ${client.address.address2}`,
};
```

Then, you can pass the data to the table:

```
<MaterialTable columns={columns} data={newData} />
```

---

`note`: I've used [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) here, because it's a little easier to read - but the code above is doing the following:

```js
const newData = {
  fullName: client.firstname + ' ' + client.lastname,
  fullAddress: client.address.address1 + ', ' + client.address.address2,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers will only work if there is no search required in the material-table, if the search is required then you will have to add "customFilterAndSearch" to the answer as below-

```
 const columns = [
        {
          title: 'Name',
          render: client => `${client.firstname} ${client.lastname}`,
          customFilterAndSearch: (term, client) => (client.firstname.toLowerCase() + ' ' + client.lastname.toLowerCase()).indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        }
      ]
```